# Multi-module Maven project : child C require child B but build error telling parent A is not found

Tags: java, docker, maven, dependencies

I have a problem when building specific module of my Maven projects
Project structure is like this :

data-importer (parent A)

|____ spring-batch (child B, jar)

|____ docker (child C)

I'm using IntelliJ (but tried with CLI and same behaviour) to build, when I'm building from the parent pom there is no problem but when I'm trying to build firstly spring-batch then docker I have the current error :

```
Could not find artifact ***.****.****.****:data-importer:pom:develop in nexus (http://**********/repository/maven-dev-group/)
```

I don't know why it's trying to get parent's pom, even if I have defined relativePath in child's POMs

I have the following POM (without the confidential parts) :

**data-importer (parent A)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>*******</groupId>
   <artifactId>data-importer</artifactId>
   <version>develop</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <name>data-importer</name>

   <description>data importer application for *</description>

   <parent>
      <groupId>*****.*****.******</groupId>
      <artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <relativePath/>
   </parent>

   <properties>
      some versions
   </properties>

   <modules>
      <module>spring-batch</module>
      <module>docker</module>
   </modules>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
         <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>*.*.*.*</groupId>
            <artifactId>data-importer-spring-batch</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

**spring-batch (child A) **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>****.****.**.***</groupId>
        <artifactId>data-importer</artifactId>
        <version>develop</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>data-importer-spring-batch</artifactId>
    <version>develop</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>spring-batch</name>

    <description>data importer application for *</description>

    <dependencies>
        some dependencies
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>data-importer</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            one dependency
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

**docker (child C)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>*.*.*.*</groupId>
        <artifactId>data-importer</artifactId>
        <version>develop</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>scpas-import</artifactId>
    <version>develop</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>docker</name>

    <description>data importer application for docker</description>

    <profiles>
        <!-- Profil commun pour générer les images docker -->
        <profile>
            <id>docker</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <!--Copy du jar spring batch dans target/docker/volumes/transferdata/import/data-importer -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-data-importer-jar-files</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <includeGroupIds>*.*.*.*</includeGroupIds>
                                    <includeArtifactIds>data-importer-spring-batch</includeArtifactIds>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>
                                        ${project.build.directory}/docker/volumes/transferdata/import/data-importer/
                                    </outputDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/docker</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${basedir}/database</directory>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>**/*</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </resource>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${basedir}/data-importer</directory>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>**/*</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </resource>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>Dockerfile</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </resource>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>docker-compose.data-importer.yml</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </resource>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>docker-entry-point.sh</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <!--Génération de image docker-->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-image</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <dockerDirectory>${project.build.directory}/docker</dockerDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>
                docker-push
            </id>
            some steps to push image in our registry
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>*.*.*.*</groupId>
            <artifactId>data-importer-spring-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Any idea why it's trying to get parent POM from registry ? (I don't want to push it as a mvn dependency)

Thx

I tried some tricks in settings.xml to never pull snapshots and releases from registry but nothing works except building full project from parent's POM

Comment: Have you tried to run `mvn install`?

Comment: Of course, first I'm doing clean install on spring-batch then clean install on docker and that's where I have the described error (error doesn't happen when clean install on parent's pom)

Comment: `mvn -pl docker --also-make install` (from project root) should force maven to build sibling modules the current module depends on.

Comment: Thx for your answer but as I said I'm trying to build each module separately (the final purpose is to finish my CI/CD implementation with one job for each module)
Building full project from project root is working (and that's why I currently have in my pipeline)

Comment: My command above only builds the `docker` module (+ its dependencies). If we want to build everything once and only once, we need more information on the whole pipeline setup.

Comment: In which module do you get this error: `Could not find artifact ***.****.****.****:data-importer:pom:develop` does not show the need information ...also there are usually more information on the console in such cases...

Comment: I have this error when trying to clean install module docker :

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project scpas-import: Could not resolve dependencies for project *.*.*.*:scpas-import:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at *.*.*.*:data-importer-spring-batch:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for *.*.*.*:data-importer-spring-batch:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find *.*.*.*:data-importer:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in http://****:*/repository/maven-dev-group/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: (I tried changing the version with "SNAPSHOT" to see if there is special policies on my companie's registry
I have tried to set "updatePolicy" to never for snapshots in my settings.xml but no changes

Comment: One thing is that `data-importer-spring-batch` is requested in your dependency-plugin configuration but it is missing as a dependency in module: `scpas-import` which means Maven can not find out the correct build order...

Comment: What is my "reactor" ? Sorry for the noobies question I don't usually work with Maven
But I check my local .m2/repository and after building spring-batch I do have it in my repo
Just don't understand why it's trying to get data-importer:pom (the parent)

Comment: Best would be to make an example project on Github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since access to the parent-POM is given, you can just locally install it beforehand.

This will solve looking parent up a repository.

What you need is to call Maven with -N (non-recursively) option `mvn install -N` and then you should be able to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much mate one more hour and I would have give up but you trick is perfect for my case !